# CakePHP get answers to queries that doesn't belong to user

Tags: mysql, cakephp, associations

I am using CakePHP 3.6.4 and I have a issue with my query system. A user can make a query and then superusers can attend his query and give him answers.

I have this tables and this data:

[image]

Each user have queries that belong to them and each query have multiple answer that belong to the query itself.

I want to retrieve all the answers of the query no matter who wrote the answer and get also the user data of the person that wrote the answer.

I have this code in my view function of my QueriesController:

```
public function view($id) {
    $query = $this->Queries->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Categories', 'Subcategories', 'Answers.Users']
    ]);

    $this->set('query', $query);
}
```

The problem with this function is that is only retrieving the answers that were wrote by the user itself:
[image]
As you can see, it's only retrieving the answers with the user_id 1, which is the user id that i'm logged in.

Thanks!

Comment: how did you set your relationships?

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/2a47c58ecc946cbcfd6c4f2380d5020d.png

Comment: Should work. Just a hint, try to contain 'Answers' too and not just Answrs.Users